# A light switch shows power going to it when in the off position

Tags: switch

A light switch shows power going into it when in the off position.  When switched on, the light comes on but the tester shows no power going into the switch.

Comment: In what way does it "show" power going into it? Is it lighted when the switch is in the off position, making it easier to see in the dark and/or know that an otherwise not visible light (such as one in a basement or garage) is turned off?

Comment: what sort of "tester" are you using?

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like the switch was installed in the neutral,  that should be corrected.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/518257/what-is-switched-neutral

Comment: Down vote reversed, there are several possibilities this is one. The measurement method could cause the other as I answered, down vote from one of our internet only folks?

Comment: true I  automatically assumed a non contact voltage detector. if it was a different type of tester it could actually be a normal behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Measuring across a switch with it open you will read voltage, in the closed position nothing but the light works.